# listen to standard Toast message in a LWC cmp

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

In my Opportunity flexi page, I have related list of Event on the right hand panel, all in a same flexi page. When I make changes/add a record to Event, I need to initialize a pop modal which is embedded inside the parent lwc cmp (left hand, main pannel). In aura there was a capability to listen to toastmsg but i'm not sure how to achieve this in lwc. I have tried this code but not getting any results. Is it even possible in LWC

```
//Code from Parent lwc 
constructor() {
    super();

    this.template.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', this.handleToastEvent.bind(this));
}
handleToastEvent (){
        console.log('toast')
    }
```

Comment: I think, in theory, you can add a listener to window, e.g. `window.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', (event) => this.handleToastEvent(event))`. Give it a try?

Comment: I did try this approach but it didn't work

Comment: @sfdcfox this approach work when you publish a custom toast msg but with Standard toast msg this approach doesn't work.

Comment: What if you enable Lightning Web Security? This may be related to Locker Service. Do you get an error in the Developer Console when trying to add the event? I'll play around with this and see if I can get it working.

Comment: did you figure out anything to listen standard toast events ?

Comment: @brahma couldn't find a way to listen standard toast events in lwc cmp. It is possible in Aura though

Comment: @Maverick thanks for your reply, you are able to use aura to listen standard toast events, is that correct ?

Comment: @brahma,  Yes

<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.onShowToast}" />

use force:showToast to listen to standard toast msg